# Running PostGIS Commands on Clustered DB

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgis, stado

Using Postgresql in clustered database (stado) on two nodes, I want to test this query:

```
select id,position,timestamp from table t1 WHERE id!=0 AND ST_Intersects ((Select ST_Buffer_Meters(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(61.4019,15.218205), 4326) ,1160006)),position) AND timestamp Between '2013-10-01' and '2013-12-30';
```

When I run it in command line or psql (on coordinator), I get this error:

```
Encountered ")" at line 1, column 171.
```

While other sql commands (insert, update, select... etc) are working fine. also Geometry columns seems okay in the table so i don't think there is a problem with installing PostGIS.

Comment: This really is me grasping at straws, but I have seen rogue spaces cause problems when calling functions: `ST_Intersects (`.

Comment: what should i do to resolve it?

Comment: Try removing the space from between `ST_Intersects` and the `(`?

Comment: thanks but just tried it. didn't work.

Comment: ST_Buffer_Meters is not an official function, though looking at it, is is composed of other Postgis functions. I would recommend using ST_Transform to convert the lat/lon to whatever local projected coordinate system you are using, and then you can do distance in meters. And don't post examples with non-standard functions :-)

Answer (score 2):

Generally-speaking, don't buffer a geometry to do a proximity search. With the above attempt, it is for just one point geometry, but in other queries you could be potentially buffering all the geometries of a table, which would make the query expensive since it would need to create new geometries and would not be able to use indexes. **Use [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) instead**.

ST_DWithin with `geometry` types will use the same distance units as the the spatial reference system. So for SRID=4326, this is in degrees, which is not helpful in any way. However, if `position` is a `geography` type, ST_DWithin will use distance arguments in meters, which is much more useful. So the WHERE filter would look like:

```
WHERE id <> 0
  AND ST_DWithin(ST_MakePoint(61.4019, 15.218205)::geography, position, 1160006)
...
```

This will do a proximity search of positions that are 1160006 m or 1160 km from the queried location (which, by the way is **not** in Sweden, if that's where you were thinking). If `position` is a `geometry` type, you can either consider changing the type, or do a cast (`position::geography`) or an index of that cast operation.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the function `ST_Buffer_Meters()` in the PostGis manual, only [`ST_Buffer()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html)

Either way, I can't imagine any function would require a subquery as parameter. Try instead:

```
SELECT id,position,timestamp
FROM   table t1
WHERE  id <> 0
AND    ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer_Meters(ST_SetSRID(
                     ST_MakePoint(61.4019, 15.218205), 4326), 1160006), position)
AND    timestamp BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND '2013-12-30';
```

And don't use `timestamp` as identifier. It's a base type name and a [reserved word in SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Comment: It turns out ST_Buffer_Meters is a function someone created, see: <a href="http://www.gistutor.com/postgresqlpostgis/6-advanced-postgresqlpostgis-tutorials/58-postgis-buffer-latlong-and-other-projections-using-meters-units-custom-stbuffermeters-function.html">st_buffer_meters</a> This seems a bit pointless, when all you need to do is use use ST_Transform to convert to a projected coordinate system when you can then use meters.